# Java 8 HashSet error

Tags: java, hash, set

I'm trying to create a HashSet of type byte in my class, like so:

```
public HashSet<byte> transparent;
```

But the eclipse error message shows:

```
Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ReferenceType
```

I don't know what this is, or what it means! I am a bit of a coding newbie, especially for java 8. I am not even sure if that's the problem!

Comment: May have actually just been a bug. I tried creating the same line a different way, with no errors.

Comment: Generic type parameters cannot be primitives.

Comment: use Byte Object instead of a primitive byte eg. public HashSet<Byte> transparent;

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the byte wrapper class Byte. Generics cannot use primitive types